# Compute characteristic function of R.V without using its explicit distribution

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let X and Y be jointly distributed r.v.'s such that

$$ Y |X = x \in Bin(n,x)$$
$$ X\in U(0,1) $$

Compute the characteristic function of Y and Cov(X,Y) (without using the explicit distribution of Y).

I'm completely at a loss here, any guidance on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the quantities you are after are of the form $\mathbb{E}\left[ f(Y) \right]$, try rewriting this expectation as $\mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ f(Y) | X \right] \right]$

Comment: Thank you, this solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the hint already suggests, you should use the conditional expectation. Let us start with the characteristic function:

$$
\mathbb{E}\big[e^{i \xi Y}\big] = \mathbb{E}_X \bigg[ \mathbb{E}\big[e^{i \xi Y} \big\vert X = x\big] \bigg]
$$
For given $x$ the characteristic function is easy to compute by means of the binomial theorem and you will come to the conclusion:
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[e^{i \xi Y} \big\vert X = x\big] = (1 +x(e^{i\xi} - 1))^n
$$
Now $x$ is distributed uniformly in $[0,1].$ Hence the characterisic function is:
$$
\mathbb{E}_X[(1 +x(e^{i\xi} - 1))^n] = \int_0^1 (1 +x(e^{i\xi} - 1))^n \ dx  = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{e^{i\xi(n+1)} - 1}{e^{i \xi}- 1}
$$
Now let us pass to the covariance:
$$
Cov(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu_X)(Y - \mu_Y)]
$$
where with $\mu$ I indicate the mean. Now we know that $\mu_X = 1/2.$ But we do not know $\mu_Y.$ You could get this value from the characteristic function. But in the spirit of this exercise you could also find it with the usual trick:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}\big[ \mathbb{E}[Y \vert X = x] \big] = \int_0^1nx \ dx = \frac{n}{2}.
$$

Finally one can turn to the covariance. But I think the point should be clear now, so I will not write down the solution. All you need to do is apply the same trick... If you need some additional detail please ask.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, the rewrite to double expectation solved it for me!